# ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: java, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I want to insert record in oracle11g database table. I am calling a stored procedure from java.
While executing stored procedure I am getting following error.

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month.
```

I am converting my date from String to Date  in java as follows

```
date=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(visitDate);
```

In my stored procedure I have following insert query

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_VISIT(p_visit_date varchar2)
insert into visit(VISIT_ID,visit_date) values
(frc.SEQ_VISIT.nextval,nvl(to_date(p_visit_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi am'), 
sysdate));
END CREATE_VISIT;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a real `DATE` for the `p_visit_date` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You have a `String` in Java.  You convert that to a `Date` in Java.  So far, presumably, so good.

Your procedure, however, accepts a `varchar2`.  So at some point the `Date` that you constructed is being explicitly or implicitly cast to a `varchar2`.  You don't say where that is happening (in Java or in PL/SQL) or whether it is being done explicitly or implicitly.  If the conversion is being done implicitly in PL/SQL, then that would use your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which may be different for different sessions in the same database.  In a default US-based install of the database and of the client, that would be `DD-MON-RR`.

Within your procedure, you then call `to_date` on the string that was passed in using an explicit format mask.  If the string that is passed in is not in the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi am` you'll either get an error or, worse, you'll get an incorrect result (this is the old question of whether the string 01/02/03 represents January 2, 2003 or February 1, 2003 or February 3, 1901).

If we guess that the `Date` in Java is being implicitly cast to a `varchar2` using your session's default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of `DD-MON-YYYY`, then we can see why your `to_date` conversion would fail.  If you have a `Date` of May 30, 2014, for example, that would be implicitly cast to the string "30-MAY-14".  If you then try to cast that back to a `date` using `to_date` and a format mask of `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi am`, Oracle would try to convert the 30 from your string to a month and raise an error since there is no 30th month.

Realistically, you should be using the proper data type throughout and you should be avoiding implicit casts like the plague.  If you declare your procedure to take a `date` parameter, then you can pass a `Date` from your Java code and omit the `to_date` call in your procedure.  The `Date` will be passed from Java to PL/SQL without needing to be converted to a `varchar2` and then converted back to a `date` and you won't have to worry about making sure that all your format masks align throughout your code base.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_VISIT(p_visit_date date)
AS
BEGIN
  insert into visit(VISIT_ID,visit_date) 
    values (frc.SEQ_VISIT.nextval,nvl(p_visit_date, sysdate);
END CREATE_VISIT;
```